# What is the equivalent of button3_Click(sender, e); in Java?

Tags: java, swing, action, call, jbutton

What is the equivalent of calling `button3_Click(sender, e);` in Java?

I am trying to make a text field action (hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>) fire a button's code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
final JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me!");
JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
InputMap inputMap = txt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actionMap = txt.getActionMap();
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), 13);
actionMap.put(13, new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        btn.doClick();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextListener for TextField like

```
public void textValueChanged(TextEvent e) { 
  // call doClick();
}
```

For Button use ActionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
```

call doClick() method refer
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29

Comment: please to change TextListener to DocumentListener